# Customize Google Visualization: GeoChart data color

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to compare two WordPress themes using the Google geo chart. But not getting desired color output

```
google.charts.load('current', {
'packages':['geochart'],
'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
        [["Country","Automotive Theme","Car Dealer Theme"],
        ["IN",1,1],
        ["US",1,1],
        ["PL",0,0],
        ["BD",0,0],
        ["ID",0,1],
        ["ES",1,3],
        ["CA",1,1],
        ["NL",0,0]]
        );


    var options = {
        colors: ["#000", "#858585"],
        legend: 'none',
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

In "Es"(Spain) the Car Dealer Theme has more points so the color of Spain is "#858585" but in "ID"(Indonesia) also Car Dealer Theme has more points but "ID" is of "#000" color why?

Comment: unless specified, regions mode is the default format. according to the data format for [regions mode](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#regions-mode-format), only two columns are needed in the data table, location and color. in this case, it appears your third column is being ignored. and the color is based on Automotive Theme, whereas ID = 0 = #000

Comment: Then how [They](https://www.similartech.com/compare/drupal-vs-joomla) manage to do this with three column

Comment: not sure, have you seen their code?

Comment: no! but this exactly what i want.